# how to debug javascript in chrome using ChromeDev Tool from eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, google-chrome-devtools

I did not found out how to run chrome from within Eclipse such that you can invoke it with the current scripts path. There is a huge difference between "running a tool" and "automatically running a debug application if it is not running already".
how to debug javascript in chrome ..

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. If you mean it will run on chrome as default browser you can set it in Window->Webrowser->Default Systemn Webrowser. Note the Chrome must be your default web-browser. Then you can do debug using developer-tools. If this not what your looking for, it will much better if your provide more details.

Comment: I have viewed your other post and now I understand it better. Well my debugging is different with yours using chrome. What I did is open the page/application in my chrome browser and then debug it there.

Answer (score 1):

Please examine the Wiki at http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com - it has exhaustive instructions on remote debugging.